# Showing HighCharts series name on x-axis and in legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to create a Column chart using Highcharts that show multiple series for one point in time only and I would like to show show the name of the series on the x-axis as well as being able to hide and show each series using the legend.
The closest I have been able to get to what I'm trying to achieve is by adding the categories and having multiple series.

```
xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Tokyo',
                'New York',
                'London',
                'Berlin'
            ]
        }
```

and then adding multiple series with only one data point in each series

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, null,null,null]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [null, 83.6,null,null]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [null, null, 48.9,null]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data:[null, null, null, 42.4]
        }]
```

The problem is that while this only shows one series for each point on the x-axis, Highcharts allocates space for each of the other series and when hiding a series only the series will be hidden not the label on the x-axis.
link to jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/

Comment: I've made it a bit better, but still needs work: http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/4/

Answer (score 5):

Set `grouping: false` in plotOptions, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/md2zk/5/

Comment: Quite the same final result as the changes I've posted on the comments, but when you hide a series, the column is still there.

Comment: It's not possible to 'hide' category on a chart. You will need to set new categories, reorganize series etc..

Comment: Exactly. That's why I didn't post my changes as a solution. It involves a bit more work to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you! Changing the grouping made it look a whole lot better. I did get a little bit closer to what I would like by removing the nulls at the end of the data. This allows you to hide the series to the right, but obviously not a solution yet. http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/6/

Comment: Can anybody suggest that how to do it in Pie chart?

Comment: Do what ? :)  In pie chart, there's no `grouping` option. There's also no xAxis, so you want to do something with legend?

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to hide Category along with the column.please go through the link given below . hope this will help.

[http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/633/](http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/631/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
           type: 'category',
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            },   
        },
        plotOptions: {

             series: {
              grouping: false,
              events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                debugger;
                    if (this.visible) {
                                        this.setData([], false)
                                         } 
                     else {
                                            this.setData([this.chart.series[this.index].userOptions], true);
                                            }
                }
            },
             borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                //style: {
                //    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                //},

            },
          },
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [{name : 'Tokyo',y:49.9}],
            y: 49.9

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [{name : 'New York',y:83.6}],
            y: 83.6

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [{name : 'London',y:48.9}],
            y: 48.9
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data:[{name : 'Berlin',y: 42.4}],
            y: 42.4
        }],
          navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: this doesn't put the data back in afterwards